# How to split events from RabbitMQ to ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, queue, elasticsearch-dsl

I just started to study RabbitMq and ElasticSearch and therefore the question arose - how best way to send like action create/delete to queue?

I have two services: base service on PHP and second search service on Python.
And requests are sent between them via a RabbitMQ

1. From the first service I send data to be added to the elastic database via a queue RabbitMQ
2. On the Python service side, I use ElasticSearch-DSL to save the document in the ElasticSearch index

Now I have to add a separation between creating and deleting product from ES.

Would it be correct to do this:

1. When I adding data about product to the queue, add parameter like "action" with values "create" or "delete", or one boolean "delete" param;
2. Next, on the Python side make a check on this action value and execute save() or delete() methods

Maybe there is a better solution?